# Is there a way to use linq query with DateTime and a string working together in the same request?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I am trying do a linq query where `DateTime()` is one of the requirements.  It looks like this:

```
viewModel.MyModels = db.MyModels.Where(cd => cd.Date == Convert.ToDateTime(theDate).Where(cd => cd.itemOne == 8).Include(i => i.AnotherModel);
```

This works with a string but when I tried doing `Convert.ToDateTime(theDate)` I get a message that says `DateTime` does not have a definition for `Where`.

Is there another way that I can get the same result without having to convert all of my `DateTime` values to `string`?

Comment: I think you missed a parenthesis there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a paren?

```
 viewModel.MyModels = db.MyModels.Where(cd => cd.Date == Convert.ToDateTime(theDate)).Where(cd => cd.itemOne == 8).Include(i => i.AnotherModel);
```

Comment: I'm so embarrassed... Thanks you guys!!!